# Start multiple threads given a list of parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pthreads

Let's say I have a list of strings that will be the parameters of a function.

How do I start `n` threads (n being the length of the list of parameters), all executing the same function, each one with a parameter from the list?

Comment: that's too broad. And note that if you want to make processing faster, threads won't help as python uses GIL (global interpreter lock). You'll have to use multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Well but, how do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
import threading

single_params = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
threads = []
# f() will be a function that takes a single string parameter 

for p in single_params: 
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=f, args=(p))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
```

Comment: You did not mention the threads in any way

Comment: True. I assumed you knew how to start threads. If not, this should be helpful https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: Could you be more clear? I mean, I know how to start threads one by one by hand, but can I automate the process, I don't know, with a for loop?

Comment: Oh I get it now. Let me update

Comment: I updated it but consensus seems that multiprocessing is the way to go